# I'm using commerce js on my website, but in the description box, it displays a <p> tag

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, dynamic, e-commerce, commerce.js

I'm creating my first website with reactjs and commerce js, but the description box in commerce js isn't functioning.

This is description box of commerce js:

[image: this is description box of commerce js]

This is my code in react:

[image: this is my code in react]

Here is p tag in output:

[image: Here is p tag in output]

Comment: Please post your code directly into the question in place of putting its screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Commerce.js uses HTML in the description field for products. Modern JavaScript frameworks such as React will not allow you to render external HTML by default for security reasons. You have two options:

1. You can use [React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), if you trust the Commerce.js API's response:

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: product.description}} />
```

2. You can strip HTML from the `product.description` variable and render plain text instead. Example package to help with this might be https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags

Answer (score 0):

1. I simply used `.slice(3,-4)` method on description string and it does the job.
2. Also, you can type `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: product.desctiption}}`